# Calling a class variable into build.properties

Tags: java, gradle

I'm sort of testing/ correcting and old gradle project to build an RPM with a tool that automatizes the import of files to a server without doing it by hand.

However this tool requires a file that is used by this proprietary software and uses it do know which dirs and libs are needed to be used. And at this point is necessary to generate the RPM and copy the file by hand the the tool's bin folder and I wanted to incorporate that file into the RPM without passing the full path to the file since the software can be used by anyone and the dirs for the software might be different from environment to environment.

On of the classes has the following variables declared:

```
private static final String DB_USER          = "db_user";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD      = "db_password";
private static final String DB_URL           = "db_url";
private static final String W_HOME           = "w_home";
private static final String W_LOGIN          = "w_login";
private static final String W_LOGIN_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String W_LOGIN_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String W_SERVER_URL     = "w_server_url";
```

The w_home is the path used to read where the software is installed and by using that variable in the build.gradle I could easily pass the folders and the file name and get it into the RPM package.

My question if its even possible to call java variables or the get of that variable into the build.gradle

Edit: adding the gradle task

```
task buildRpm(type: Rpm, overwrite: true, dependsOn: build) {
    packageName = applicationName
    release = rpm_release
    arch = NOARCH
    os = LINUX
    epoch = git.head().time
    summary = "Import"
    license = 'Proprietary'

    user User
    permissionGroup Group

    //THIS DIRECTORY SHOULD ALREADY BE PRESENT
    into(Home){
        addParentDirs = false
        fileMode 0644
        dirMode 0755

        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/lib")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/config")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/bin")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/logs", 0777)

        from(jar.outputs.files) {
            into "${ packageName }/lib"
        }

        from(configurations.runtime) {
            into "${ packageName }/lib"
        }

        from('lib') {
            into "${ packageName }/lib"
        }

        from('src/dist/config') {
            exclude 'log4j2.xml'
            into "${ packageName }/config"
        }

        from('src/dist/config/log4j2.xml') {
            into "${ packageName }/config"
            fileType CONFIG | NOREPLACE
        }

        from('out/scripts') {
            into "${ packageName }/bin"
            fileMode 0755
        }
    }
    requires('java', '2000:1.8.0_121', GREATER | EQUAL)
}
```

Comment: You can use these variables in the build.gradle by enriching the buildscript classpath (and making them public). However it is very hard to give you a complete answer if you do not provide the relevant parts of your build.gradle. Where is this class located ? Is it part of the project or somewhere in a jar ?

Comment: The class is located in part of the project in `/src/main/java/importTool/configurations`I'll edit the main post to include the classpath and task of gradle

Answer (score 0):

If the class containing the constants is part of your project, one way to achieve your goal would be to dynamically load the output jar in your RPM generating task then extract the desired values via reflection :

```
// Put this in your RPM task
URL[] urls = [new URL("file:///" + jar.archivePath.absolutePath)]
def loader = new URLClassLoader(urls)
// className is the fully qualified name of the configuration class
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass(className)

def field = clazz.getDeclaredField("W_HOME")
field.setAccessible(true) // This is needed for private fields
String home = field.get(null)
```

Since your class has constants that are apparently intended to be used externally, there is no point in making them `private`.

Of course, you'll have to adapt the above snippet if you have some custom build chain that does not use the standard `jar` task.